# How to execute a statement only if a condition is met in R-exams

Tags: r-exams

I intend the code to run only if c is different from a square less than 36, otherwise try again ...

```
c<-sample((1:36),1)
if(c==1|c==4|c==9|c==16|c==25|c==36){

}else{
  
}
```

Comment: Why don't you choose a sample from `c(1,4,9,16,25,36)`? `c <- sample( (1:5)^2,1)`.

Comment: Thanks, uzsolt. Her response broadens my range of options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simplier condition:

```
if (c %in% (1:5)^2) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and accurate responses !!!

Comment: Excellent code optimization. Thank you very much uzsolt.

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
gotit <- FALSE

while (!gotit)
{
  c<-sample((1:36),1)
  if(c==1|c==4|c==9|c==16|c==25|c==36){
    gotit <- FALSE
  } else {
    gotit <- TRUE
    cat("Got it!\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left. Then the question is flagged as resolved here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it works for you or otherwise refine the question so that we can fully resolve it...